# Displaying foundation tool-tip in angular 2 so that it always show in the view port

Tags: angular, zurb-foundation

I have an issue with foundation tool-tip, the element on which it is being applied is at one of the corners of the view-port. I would like to know if there is any possibility to dynamically change the tooltipplacement either using foundation or any suitable library compatible with angular 2 and foundation. I found the following library [Angular Foundation 6](https://circlingthesun.github.io/angular-foundation-6/) but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ng-bootstrap tooltip component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/api), it allows you to specify the placement:

> placement  Type: "top" | "bottom" | "left" | "right" Default value:
>   top — initialized from NgbTooltipConfig service Placement of a
>   tooltip. Accepts: "top", "bottom", "left", "right"

Comment: Dear Graham, thank you for your [suggested-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17159947) relative to [my meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355753/cleaning-posts-with-omploader-org-images). Yet, I believe you did not properly save the post: the edited post still looks incomprehensible and is probably better suited for deletion or deeper refactoring. Also, when editing with less than 2000 Reputation, it's nice to link to the Meta post that is relative to an edit suggestion (It was only lucky to be seen by me: other reviewers may not be aware of the meta post)